# How can i install PIP on my windows machine in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pip

I have tried many different things such as `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py` and also adding it to the PATH but none have worked. When I try to run anything with pip I get this error...

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

can anyone help with this or point me to somewhere that may help as well?[image]

Comment: What sort of terminal are you using? The error looks like a powershell error, but the commands you've listed look like linux ones

Comment: @Elenchus yes i am using powershell in vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download get-pip.py by following this link: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. Alternatively, use curl:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then run the following command in the folder where you have downloaded get-pip.py:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Did this, still get the message saying its not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: could you please attatch screenshots of terminal where you first executes this `python get-pip.py` and then write `pip`

Comment: Sure. When typing in python get-pip.py nothing happens either, it is in the same folder

Comment: please attach the screenshots

Comment: just added the picture.

Comment: i meant attatch it in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218788/discussion-between-divyessh-maheshwari-and-mferraro).